# is the keyword 'this' is a static thing..?

Tags: java

well i was writing a program and stuck at a line that why it's working...here is my code.

```
public class X
{
    int a;
    public void func(int a)
    {
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(this.a);
        System.out.print(X.this.a);
    }
    public static void main(String ... args)
    {
        X var=new X();
        var.func(5);
    }
}
```

it's giving me output as-

5
0
0

but why X.this working because we all know "this" is non-static from this example-

```
public class Me
{
    static Me m,m1;
    int x;
    public  Me Me1()
    {
        System.out.println("yes");
        return Me.this;
    }

    public static void main(String ... args)
    {
        m=new Me();
        m1=new Me().Me1();
        System.out.println(m.x+" "+m1.x);
    }

}
```

now this program is running but if i put

```
public static Me Me1()
{
    System.out.println("yes");
    return Me.this;
}
```

then it gives the error "non-static variable this can not be referenced from a static context"

i know it is because the static function comes in the existence before object creation so that we can not use "this" in any non-static function.

my question is why "this" can be referenced like Me.this from a non-static function without any error..?

Comment: Format, format, format :)

Comment: Read a good tutorial book on Java and on [object-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). We might not have hours to teach you the basics.

Comment: `Me.this` in that context is the same as just `this`

Answer (score 1):

**why "this" can be referenced like Me.this from a non-static function without any error?**

Because the language specification says so. Java allows for inner/nested instances to access the (instance of the) class(es) in which they are defined (outer classes).

From the [language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3):

> **15.8.4. Qualified this**
>
> Any lexically enclosing instance (§8.1.3) can be referred to by explicitly qualifying the keyword this.
>
> Let C be the class denoted by ClassName. Let n be an integer such that C is the n'th lexically enclosing class of the class in which the qualified this expression appears.
>
> The value of an expression of the form ClassName.this is the n'th lexically enclosing instance of this.
>
> The type of the expression is C.
>
> It is a compile-time error if the current class is not an inner class of class C or C itself.

So since you are within the `Me` class, you can use `this` and `Me.this` and they are equivalent. If you were to access and `Me` from a nested instance, you would have to use `Me.this`.

Regarding the use of `this` in a static context. Since `this` references the current instance of the class you're working with, it cannot be used in a static method. A static method does not belong to any *instance*, but the class itself. Also from the specification (15.8.3 - See previous link):

> When used as a primary expression, the keyword `this` denotes a value that is a reference to the object for which the instance method was invoked (§15.12), or to the object being constructed.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a non-static function there is always a target object, either specified or implied. For example, if you call System.out.println, the target object is the one referenced by System.out. If you call a method in your own class without a specified target, the target is `this`.

The method can then use `this` to reference the target object. As already pointed out, `X.this` in class `X` is the same as `this`.

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to an **current instance** of a class.

On the other hand, static variables/methods are those that don't work on the instance variable of the class (so no instance of the class is available). This is why you can't use the `this` keyword in a static method.

Look at this easier to understand example:

```
public class Person
{
    String name;
    public Person(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void talk(String line)
    {
        System.out.println(name+": "+line);
    }
}
```

The usage will be as:

```
Person a,b;
a = new Person("A");
b = new Person("B");
a.talk("hi!");
b.talk("hi");
```

Notice how the `talk()` method makes use of the member(instance) variable `name`. The `talk()` could be rewritten as:

```
public void talk(String line)
{
    System.out.println(this.name+": "+line);
}
```

That is why `a.talk()` would print "A: " before the message whereas, `b.talk()` would print "B: " before the message.

Now let's go ahead and add another method to the class:

```
public class Person
{
    String name;
    public Person(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void talk(String line)
    {
        System.out.println(name+": "+line);
    }

    public static void info()
    {
        System.out.println("You can create a person, using this class and make him talk to through the console");
    }
}
```

You can use the `info()` as:

```
Person.info();
```

Notice that I'm using the class name and not the instance name. This is because static (shared) variables are shared among all the instance of the class, and static methods have access only to static variables.

Try changing the `info()` to and you will get an error:

```
public static void info()
{
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

The above code will throw you an error. Because name is an instance variable i.e. using name in the method is the same as using `this.name`. But `this` doesn't exist in the current context.

Always remember,
1. Use static variables/methods only if the attribute/behavior is supposed to be the same **irrespective** of the instance variables.
2. You can't call a non-static method from static method (or use instance variables) directly

```
public static void info()
{
    talk();
}
```

Will not work because  it is the same as writing `this.talk()`
You'll have to do something like this instead:

```
public static void info()
{
    Person a = new Person("Example");
    a.talk();
}
```

The design of your code needs to be improved. Read books on Java and OO programming